# Admob registering many test ID's

Tags: android, admob

I am using Admobs on my app and have recently got some more handsets to help with testing. The problem is I can only seem to enter one device ID as a test client. anyone know if I can add more than 1?

Answer (score 0):

if setting them in layout file (XML) just use comma to separate ids:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    [...]
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,D6A5B1F6DE9E1261C8C2A178418CFD52"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
/>
```